# Не получается вывод среднего значения Map (Java)

Tags: java, map

Не могу вывести среднюю цену с каждой категории.
В Классе **Product**, в поле были объявлены `category`, `name`, `price`. А также конструктор и *геттеры-сеттеры.*

Создал также несколько экземпляров в методе `Main`.

```
Product p1 = new Product("Vehicle", "Kia_Rio", 5_000_000);
        Product p2 = new Product("Smartphone", "Iphone 11", 300_000);
        Product p3 = new Product("Smartphone", "Iphone_11_Pro", 340_000);
        Product p4 = new Product("Smartphone", "Iphone_12", 400_000);
        Product p5 = new Product("Vehicle", "Toyota_Prius", 3_750_000);
        Product p6 = new Product("Laptop", "MacBook_Pro", 650_000);
        Product p7 = new Product("Shoes", "Crocks", 25_000);
        Product p8 = new Product("Shoes", "Nike", 35_000);

        Product[] products = new Product[]{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8};
```

> Подсчитал количество товаров в каждой категории.

```
Map<String, Integer> productCount = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (productCount.containsKey(products[i].getCategory())) {
                productCount.put(products[i].getCategory(), productCount.get(products[i].getCategory()) + 1);
            } else {
                productCount.put(products[i].getCategory(), 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(productCount);
```

`Результат:`

```
{Vehicle=2, Laptop=1, Shoes=2, Smartphone=3}
```

> Подсчитал общую стоимость цен всех категории.

```
 Map<String, Integer> averagePrice = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (averagePrice.containsKey(products[i].getCategory())) {
                averagePrice.put(products[i].getCategory(), averagePrice.get(products[i].getCategory()) + products[i].getPrice());
            } else {
                averagePrice.put(products[i].getCategory(), products[i].getPrice());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(averagePrice);
```

> Результат:

```
{Vehicle=8750000, Laptop=650000, Shoes=60000, Smartphone=1040000}
```

> Но не могу вывести среднюю цену всех категории:

```
for (int k = 0; k < averagePrice.size(); k++) {
            if (averagePrice.containsKey(products[k].getCategory())) {
                averagePrice.put(products[k].getCategory(), averagePrice.get(products[k].getPrice() / products[k].getCategory().length()));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(averagePrice);
```

> Но выводит такой результат:

```
{Vehicle=null, Laptop=650000, Shoes=60000, Smartphone=null}
```

В чем ошибка и как это решить? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В `averagePrice` фактически накапливается *сумма* по категориям, поэтому для расчёта средней величины следует сумму разделить на количество элементов в категории:

```java
averagePrice.forEach((product, totalPrice) -> 
    averagePrice.put(product, totalPrice / productCount.get(productPrice))
);
```

Однако, *целочисленные* средние значения могут быть неточными в общем случае, потому вероятно следовало бы накапливать суммарное значение как `Double`.

---

Также вместо использования отдельных мап для подсчёта количества продуктов, суммарных и средних значений, можно было бы воспользоваться Stream API и объектом [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html), который возвращается при помощи [`Collectors.summarizingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```java
Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> priceStatsByCategory = products
        .stream() // Stream<Product>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Product::getCategory, // ключ - ссылка на геттер категорий
            Collectors.summarizingInt(Product::getPrice) // значение - статистика по ценам по категориям
        ));
```

Тогда корректные средние значения можно просмотреть так:

```java
priceStatsByCategory.forEach((product, stats) -> System.out.println(
    product + " avg.price = " + stats.getAverage()
));
```

Comment: Узнал что в моем коде идет пробег по size, т.е. по словарю. А нужно по ключам. Сделал через KeySet но выходит иное. 
Set<String> keys = averagePrice.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            System.out.println(key + " = " + (averagePrice.get(key) / key.length()));
        }

Comment: Как можно организовать через keySet точнее? спасибо

Comment: Каким образом деление на длину ключа _названия_продукта_ должно вычислить среднюю цену??  Вы пытались использовать какое-либо из предложенных выше решений?